# Cannot import a module. Keeps telling me module not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

## Games.js file in the Utils folder

```
const unirest = require('unirest')

const getGame = (g) => {
    unirest.get('https://rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com/games/' + g)
    .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", '3482457f4amsh7fbc73f82300707p1955f8jsn4397e9828211')
    .end((result) => {
      let gameDesc = result.body.description.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"")
      console.log(gameDesc)
      const game = {
        name: result.body.name,
        desc: gameDesc,
        image: result.body.background_image
      }
    })
}
module.exports = getGame
```

## Index.js file in the root of the project

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios')
const unirest = require('unirest')
const getGame = require('../utils/games')

var reqData = unirest("GET", "https://rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com/games")

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  const header = {
    title: 'Game Changer',
    subtitle: 'My personal review on games i\'ve played'
  }

  // gameAPI(req.query)
  // res.render('index', {header})
  console.log(gameInfo.name)
  res.render('index', {header, gameInfo})
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  // console.log('Search Value', req.body.searchValue)
  let gameSearched = req.body.searchValue
  gameSearched = gameSearched.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '-')

  getGame(gameSearched)
        // replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"")
      const header = {
        title: 'Game Changer',
        subtitle: 'My personal review on games i\'ve played'
      }
      res.render('index', {header, game})

})

module.exports = router;
```

When I run the code, It says Error module not found. My app works fine when I have all the code in games.js in index.js, but i'm trying to seperate that code into a function in another file, then import it into index.js and call the function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might be having a problem with the file names, since you wrote that your games file is `Games.js`, but in `index.js`, you are referring to it as `games`. Check if your OS file system is case sensitive; If it is, check the module imports. The problem might lie there.